# Javascript. Convert MD5 hash into an integer

Tags: javascript, md5

Is it possible in Javascript to convert something like this: `d131dd02c5e6eec4 693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab58712467eab 4004583eb8fb7f89`, which is the result of an MD5 hash function, into an integer ?

Comment: What do you want the integer for? You could convert it to a string, but not a JavaScript number (accurately, anyways).

Comment: I'm trying to implement the Chord protocol.

Comment: The only way you could even begin to cast it as an int is by using some form of substitution to replace the letters with a number, which creates a whole set of other issues...

Comment: @AndreiBogdan: So, to implement the Chord protocol, what calculation do you need to do on the hash (as an integer)?

Comment: In the article describing the protocol it says "The consistent hash function assigns each node and key an m bit
identifier using SHA-1 as a base hash function. A node’s
identifier is chosen by hashing the node’s IP address [...]". So I can arrange these values 'around a circle', just by comparing the strings, but later on it says that each node has a list of successors: "s = successor(n+2^i), where 0 <= i <= m-1 (and all arithmetic is modulo 2^m)." m in the case of MD5 (which I'm using) is 128. I might be wrong, but I need to be able to perform modulo on the hash function. o.O

Comment: I need to have integers to find out which successors are at +1 +2 +4 +8 .... "n" above should be a number ... o.O I'm starting to think that there's something I'm not getting here, but I can't figure out what exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a hexadecimal number, so you could try using the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function and pass in a base of sixteen:

```
var num = parseInt(string, 16);
```

**Edit:  This method doesn't actually work.  See the comments for details.**

Comment: It returns a number in my console...   A huge number, but it's something.  I'm not sure how precise it ends up being though.

Comment: Very imprecise. Or, if you kept the spaces in, just the first part.

Comment: When I do `a = 'd131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89'`

`b = parseInt(a, 16)` is
`9.462148622078087e+76`

Then `b % 2` returns `0` and `b % 3` returns `2`, so wouldn't that mean it has precision about the lower digits?  Or is it lying or doing something weird?

Comment: It’s lying.  `parseInt`: ~9.462148622078087e+76. Actual value: 94621486220780871705971335405839374945966571586290374999485260302979719462793, which is evenly divisible by 3 and not by 2.

Comment: Should this answer really be accepted? It seems the comments suggest this is NOT the right approach or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: No, you're right.  I just edited the answer to say it's wrong.

Comment: If you need a nonce, you can take a substring of the hash (8, 12 octets) and then parseInt().

Comment: Agree with epx. Do you really need EVERY digit in the result? This is not reversible.

Answer (score 7):

May not be perfect, but this suited my needs

```
export function stringToIntHash(str, upperbound, lowerbound) {
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result = result + str.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  if (!lowerbound) lowerbound = 0;
  if (!upperbound) upperbound = 500;

  return (result % (upperbound - lowerbound)) + lowerbound;
}
```

Comment: I really like this solution for the fact that it's simple and (since it relies on ASCII codes) can be easily reproduced on the server, but what's missing for me in it is that I would want the probability distribution to be guaranteed to be uniform between the two bounds, assuming the input is a uniform-random-choice string.

Answer (score 4):

ES6 version, string to integer between 0-9:

```
string.split('').map(i => i.charCodeAt(0)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) % 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one https://github.com/lovell/farmhash ?

```
const farmhash = require('farmhash');
const hexDigest = crypto.createHash('md5').update().digest('hex');
farmhash.fingerprint64(hexDigest);
```